# Knockout.js: Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'applybindings'

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

Just learning Knockout and I have a curious issue.  I have this working, then performed some code cleanup and it stopped working and I get the javascript error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'applybindings'

At the top of the index page, I have these scripts loading:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-2.0.3.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.3.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/knockout-2.3.0.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/knockout-2.3.0.debug.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/ClientApp/Patient.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

... And a simple concept patient.js script:

```
var patient = function (id) {
  var self = this
  self.id = ko.observable(id);

  self.name = ko.computed(function () {
      return this.id() + "_Joe";
  }, this);
};

var patientViewModel = {
  patient: ko.observable(new patient(1))
};

$(document).ready(function () {
  ko.applybindings(patientViewModel);
});
```

I am new to javascript in general, so I am sure a few things will jump out immediately to the advanced crowd.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have error in applyBindings function name, it must be:

```
applyBindings
```

Also, you twice declare knockout.js file (knockout-2.3.0.js and knockout-2.3.0.debug.js), choose debug or minified version.

Comment: Haha, thanks my friend.  We all need to start somewhere right?  For me, it's rock bottom.  In 8 minutes, I will mark this as solved.